# WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default.firestore.collection is not

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to add test data to firestore.
but the following error happened.
I don't know how I should fix it?
What is WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5 ?
package.json is set correctly.
and the other codes work properly.

```
  connect(mapStateToProps),firestoreConnect([{ collection : 'projects' }])
```

'../../config/fireBaseConfig'

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import "firebase/storage"

  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "F_U6fgergrsyoBYrgrgrgrgrgr",
    authDomain: "test.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "stack-flow-1333f",
    storageBucket: "stack-over-1333f.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "12345678",
    appId: "1:450307196367:web:foobarfoobar",
    measurementId: "G-foobarfooboogoo"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.firestore();

export const storage = firebase.storage();
export default firebase;
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import firebase from '../../config/FireBaseConfig';

class Stack extends Component {


    handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        firebase.firestore.collection("projects").add({
            title:'TITLE_TEST',
            content:'KOREHA TEST',
            imageUrl:'',
            id: 'xxxxxxxx',
            createdAt: new Date(),
        });
    }
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.17",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "core-js": "3",
    "firebase": "^8.3.0",
ommit...
```

> TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.firestore.collection is not a function

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`firebase.firestore()`
You can remove this line

About the line
`firebase.firestore.collection(....)`
Replace it with
`firebase.firestore().collection('...')`